# Apexchart Bubble chart: Line connecting the bubbles

Tags: apexcharts

Is it possible to draw a line connecting the bubble dots within the same series? Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have a bubble chart with two or three bubbles for each series - they are the same color, but I would also like to draw a line to connect the dots.

Thanks